# What persistence behavior should I expect when in this scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a large block of code with several nested loops which needs to ultimately update many records in the database.  I am trying to minimize the number of SaveChanges() calls to Entity Framework.  Also note that we we are using the repository pattern.

Essentially I'm iterating a collection and need to update both the items in the collection and upon each iteration, another object retrieved from the db and contextualized by the item from the collection.

Sample code:

```
foreach (var outer in outerList)
            {
                obj = unit.GetRepository<MyObj>().Get(s =>
                    s.id = myId
                    ).SingleOrDefault();

                obj.value += outer.value;                    
                outer.objId = obj.objId;

                unit.GetRepository<MyOuterObj>().Update(outerObj);
                unit.GetRepository<MyObj>().Update(obj);                    
            }
            unit.Save();
```

The call to Update() performs the following:

```
public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        if(entityToUpdate is AuditModelBase)
        {
            var model = entityToUpdate as AuditModelBase;
            model.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

And the call to Save() of course performs the following:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

So my question is, as I'm reassigning obj to a different value each time through the loop, do I need Save() inside the foreach loop in order for all instances of "obj" to persist.  Or does the DbSet.Attach(obj) ensure that each individual instance is updated regardless on what I do with the object in my loop.

Or perhaps a better way to ask this is:

*Given that it looks like Attach() is pass-by-reference so therefore only my last obj will be updated, what are best practices with EF to accomplish this sort of thing (excluding the option of straight calls to SQL) ?*

Comment: So you wrote all of the code, but you want to know whether or not it will work.  Did you ever consider just executing it and finding out?

Comment: You're asking the question, "Does this particular code snippet work?"  That is best answered by running it.  It's only calling the update once, so you're not going to come up with anything that does any less.  The question of, "Is this working code good practice, or can it be made more efficient?" is a question for code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry. Once you call `Attach` on your object, it doesn't matter whether you keep a reference to it yourself or not; it should be fine.

The thing to keep in mind is that your object lives as long that it's referenced by *someone*. So, it stands to reason that calling `Attach` would cause your `DbSet` to reference your object, thus keeping it alive even after you don't reference it anymore yourself.

However, the best thing to do, in my opinion, is to just give it a try and see what happens!

Comment: Yes, this is working as you suggested in various scenarios and better yet, the context keeps track of and performs fix-ups on the relationships between the objects automatically.  So in scenarios where concurrency is not a major issue, calling the Save() as late as possible seems to be quite feasible.  Thanks so much for your helpful answer!

Comment: OK as it turns out, yes there is a reference kept, but not a copy.  Therefore in my example above, since I am assigning obj to a new object each time through the loop, everything is fine.  However, what cannot be done is to reuse the same object, passing it to Attach() and expect there to be instances in the repository.  Perhaps obvious to experienced EF developers, but not necessarily intuitive coming from the old "commit to db" world.  I had expected it to act sort of like a memory cache representation of the db, which it does not.